# How do I check that a string doesn't include any characters other than letters and numbers?

Tags: c#, regex, string, validation

This is what I have so far, but I can't find anywhere the code to say that I just want to include letters and numbers. I'm not familiar with regular expressions. Right now my code just ignores the while loop even if I include '#'.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void okBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(textBox1.Text.Contains(@"^[^\W_]*$"))
        {
            fm1.txtFileName = textBox1.Text;
            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Filename cannot include illegal characters.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Having the while loop in `button_click` handler makes your application display the message infinitely. Use an `if` statement and simply return if the condition is met. As for the condition itself, see the answers below.

Comment: Letters and numbers *in what orthography*?  Are letters in, say, Greek to be considered letters? What about symbols that are legal in file names, like "." ?

Comment: @EricLippert I thought I'd just keep it simple for now, so just the 26 letters and 10 numbers on the keyboard.

Comment: There is no such thing as "the" keyboard; on *your* keyboard you mean. Other people's keyboards have different letters on them.  I note that if you want a-z and 0-9 only then the accepted answer is wrong; `IsLetterOrDigit` accepts letters and digits in any orthography.

Comment: Ah, right. Thank you. I realised I used the char array answer anyway, looking to see if any characters in the string matched any of the characters in GetInvalidPathChars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're checking for invalid filenames, I'd use [Path.GetInvalidPathChars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars.aspx) instead:

```
char[] invalidChars = Path.GetInvalidPathChars();
if (!input.All(c => !invalidChars.Contains(c)))
{
    //invalid file name
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the method [`char.IsLetterOrDigit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cay4xx2f.aspx) to check whether a input string only contains letters or digits:

```
if (input.All(char.IsLetterOrDigit))
{
    //Only contains letters and digits
    ... 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, what is 'input' here? Would it be textBox1.Text?

Comment: @liam.burns: yes, this is just general, but you can map into your case

Comment: Good job using a built-in instead of a regex!

Comment: Thanks for the help. Just have to wait a minute to accept your answer :)

Comment: What if the length of the text is zero?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this pattern:

```
@"^[^\W_]*$"
```

`^` and `$` are anchors for begining and end of the string.

Since `\w` stands for all letters, all digits and the underscore, you must remove the underscore from your character class.

Comment: This works apart from now it won't take anything, so even if I include just letters it doesn't work. I'll edit my code at the top now.

Comment: liam, this is a Regex pattern, "contains" checks for an actual string

Answer (score 2):

this will only allow letters and digits:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

check this [website](http://regexlib.com/%28A%28MBiyWGn1yhXUMQjJ3cczaXZT9U2oRgeb4F3txPls1zyC8HVb7m547_j-s-0dU2ioSv_PrvOtfUBxxT4sgvcy2iyPcyC3RnpJLiXXvKoHeqSiyKf-GFTrd42sGYXowcToEIb9MZ_mBiigxyOdEbKnfur6guGku8Ek763cN6odgiCM241Ax3KjkvX0_NOIkp3I0%29%29/Default.aspx) all about regex.

If you want to use regex you can place this inside your button click event:
-Be sure to import the proper namespace - `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`

```
    private void okBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Match match = Regex.Match(textBox1.Text, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
        if (match.Success)
        {
            fm1.txtFileName = textBox1.Text;
            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Filename cannot include illegal characters.");
        }
    }
```